# Google Maps on Android Font

Tags: android, fonts, maps, searchbar

I am designing an App for Android and I saw this wonderful font in the search bar of the Google Maps App on my Android phone. Do you know the name or if its a font google created do you know another font which looks like this one?

Thank you for every answer!

Comment: Font identification is off-topic on Stack Overflow. You can ask on [graphicdesign.se] instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Google Product Sans Font:
https://befonts.com/product-sans-font.html

++

Answer (score 0):

It's probably Roboto, see it on Google Fonts: https://fonts.google.com/?query=roboto